¿Cómo crear un ejecutable para una aplicación JavaFX ligera?
Aprendiendo sobre Java y su universo, estoy usando JavaFX y Visual Studio Code, con el plugin de Red Hat, pero por ahora no quiero usar herramientas de compilación como Gradle o Maven, ya que las siento complicadas de usar y no entiendo su funcionalidad específica. Para crear los ejecutables .exe uso Launch4j, y me iba bien cuando hacía programas de consola sin dependencias. Sin embargo, desde que empecé a usar JavaFX para diseñar las GUI he tenido problemas. Para que carguen las dependencias, pongo en el apartado JVM options lo siguiente:
--module-path ruta\a\javafx-sdk\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

y el ejecutable creado funciona bien (quizás se demora un poco en abrir, pero ese no es el principal problema). Como pretendo distribuir mi aplicación a los usuarios finales, copio el contenido de la carpeta lib del SDK de JavaFX a la carpeta de mi proyecto, y entonces cambio la opción a --module-path .\lib. Entonces, cuando intento ejecutar el .exe, me sale este error:


Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.4/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    ... 5 more


Donde parece que no pudo inicializar los gráficos. Y según deduzco, él necesita que también esté presente el contenido de la carpeta bin del JavaFX-SDK para ejecutarse. Pero mi objetivo por ahora es hacer programas sencillos y básicos, para ir desde lo simple hasta lo complejo; y es preferible que sean lo más ligeros posible, porque no tiene gracia distribuir al usuario final un paquete de 108 MB para un Hola Mundo de ventana. Entonces, lo que quiero saber es cuál es la manera más ligera de empaquetar para su distribución un programa en Java que pueda ejecutarse como .exe con todas sus dependencias (excepto el JRE, que ya tantos lo tienen instalado que da igual). Y de ser posible, de forma portable, sin instaladores (imagínense instalar, probar y desinstalar un Hola mundo)
Gracias de antemano por cualquier contribución

Un amigo mío creó este artículo en medium. Te lo recomiendo mucho, aunque está en inglés.
https://medium.com/dev-genius/creating-a-custom-jre-with-java-modules-and-jlink-24e2cd81716a

¿qué sistema de construcción usas?

Ruslan López ninguno, ya lo dije en el post; compilo con las herramientas de la extensión del vscode, aunque he comprobado que con Gradle hay opciones automatizadas de construcción que cumplen el objetivo, aunque gradle es muy lento para mi equipo y su resultado es tan o más pesado que el que se consigue aplicando la respuesta de Iván Vázquez

JLink permite crear un runtime de Java, usa el siguiente comando para ejecutar tu aplicación.
jlink --module-path <ruta-al-JDK>/jmods;<ruta-al-JavaFX>/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --output myAppRuntime

Empaqueta con Launch4j apuntando a la ruta relativa generada por JLink y deberías tener tu ejecutable ligero .exe

Muchas gracias, me funciona, pero no es ligero (myAppRuntime pesa por sí solo 95 MB). Además, hay que especificar en module-path el directorio de jmods del JavaFX (ya lo había descargado anteriormente) con lib no me sirve. Por demás, es casi como lo que tenía hasta ahora
